# Terraform - deploy a k8s cluster with a custom infrastructure resource group name

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-aks

a client wants all Terraform deployed according to their naming conventions.
how would i edit / define the azure aks infra resource group?
I have pasted the portal insert for clarity.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `node_resource_group` argument in the `azurerm_kubernetes_cluster` resource.

Source: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/kubernetes_cluster#node_resource_group